# Show that $|\mathcal{P_0}(S)| = |\mathcal{P_0}(T)|$

Tags: proof-writing, cardinals

Let $\mathcal{P_0}(S)$ denote the collection of all countable subsets of $S$. Given that $|S| = |T| = c$, show that $|\mathcal{P_0}(S)| = |\mathcal{P_0}(T)|$.

Comment: What do you need help on exactly?

Comment: Hint. Use the known bijection between $S$ and $T$ to construct a bijeciion between their power sets that preserves everything that matters to you.

Comment: @EthanBolker Hmm. Can you please show me how? I haven't fully grasped the concept. I'm stuck at how to introduce the power set.

Comment: @user65018 has written that answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|S|=|T|=c$, there exists a bijection $f: S\to T$. Then consider a map $F: \mathcal P_0(S)\to \mathcal P_0(T)$ defined by
$$F(A)=\{y\in T\,|\,f(x)=y, x\in A\}$$
for all $A\ne\emptyset$ and $A\in \mathcal P_0(S)$, and $F(\emptyset)=\emptyset$.

- $F$ is injective: If $A,B\subseteq S$ but $A\ne B$. Then there exists, without loss of generality, some $z\in A\backslash B$. Then by definition, $f(z)\in F(A)$ but $f(z)\notin F(B)$, meaning that $F(A)\ne F(B)$.
- $F$ is surjective:For each $B\subseteq T$, notice that $F(f^{-1}(B))=B$ and $f^{-1}(B)\subseteq S$.

Together, we have shown that $F$ is bijective, and the desired result holds.

Comment: You don't have to treat the empty set as a special case. It's already correctly done with your definition of $F$.